# detect exit event in IE and Fireforx

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect the exit event on all browser, I tried this code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    var message = 'Important: Please click on \'Save\' button to leave this page.';
    if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
        event = window.event;
    }
    if (event) {
        event.returnValue = message;
    }
    return message;
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Exit your browser .... 
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

this code works in Chrome and safari but it it does'nt work in IE 11 and Fireforx 50.0.1 ... Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the response that I find, It work for me.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

  (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
  return confirmationMessage;                            //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
});
```

thank you

Comment: @Dexion it was in the link that you passed me

Answer (score 1):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) page following notes are being mentioned

> Note also, that various mobile browsers ignore the result of the event (that is, they do not ask the user for confirmation). Firefox has a hidden preference in about:config to do the same. In essence this means the user always confirms that the document may be unloaded.

The hidden keys inside `about:config` can be found with the keys `dom.disable_beforeunload` and `dom.require_user_interaction_for_beforeunload`.

Your code seems fine for the rest, so it may help to look in your config files (The note mentions mobile browsers, however I have these settings on my Desktop browser as well)

Comment: thank you for your reponse. I work on software witch will be used by clients poste, so your solution need to do this configuration in all clients posts ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with 
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(evt){ ...

Comment: it does not get called? or executes without any influence?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser

Comment: in IE it does'nt get called !

Comment: @Mouaici_Med Depending on the IE version (which is important!!) it can be that you need a different method to listen to the possible event being thrown

Comment: @Icepickle do have an idea to do it for IE?

Comment: @Mouaici_Med Yeah, in the link in my answer, there is also a link to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907(VS.85).aspx) page ;)